# Comparing each String in String array to one string of user input using nested for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to compare two strings and sum the differences of their chars. One string is a user input (input) and the other is from an array of strings (binary_patterns_array).

I would like to compare each string in the array to the input and place the sum of their differences into another int array. I have another method that iterates through the int array to find the smallest value which will give me the index of closest matching pattern. Here's the code:

```
public static int[] difference(String input, String[] binary_patterns_array){
    int[] difference_array = new int[32];
    String  binary_pattern = "";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < binary_patterns_array.length; i++){
        binary_pattern = binary_patterns_array[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++){
            if (binary_pattern.charAt(j) != input.charAt(j)){
                count += 1;
            }
         difference_array[i] = count;
        }
    }
    return difference_array;
}
```

This doesn't work but I'm not exactly sure why. The two loops do exactly what I want them to, but my if statement or the way i'm summing the differences isn't doing what I had hoped. Can anyone see any blatant mistakes? Thank you!

Comment: *isn't doing what I had hoped* -- what is it doing instead?

Comment: Can you provide an example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `count` in every pattern iteration:

```
public static int[] difference(String input, String[] binary_patterns_array){
    int[] difference_array = new int[32];
    String  binary_pattern = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < binary_patterns_array.length; i++){
        int count = 0; // moved inside the loop so it is 0 at the beginning of each pattern
        binary_pattern = binary_patterns_array[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++){
            if (binary_pattern.charAt(j) != input.charAt(j)){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        difference_array[i] = count; // moved because it is cleaner outside the inner loop
    }
    return difference_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues

1. count should be reset every time
2. Array size is hardcoded. It should be set as the size of binary_patterns_array
3. difference_array[i] should be set outside the inner loop.
4. No need to create temporary variable. It is just a memory overhead.

   ```
   public static int[] difference(String input, String[] binary_patterns_array) {
   int[] difference_array = new int[binary_patterns_array.length];

   for (int i = 0; i < binary_patterns_array.length; i++) {
       int count = 0;
       for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
           if (binary_patterns_array[i].charAt(j) != input.charAt(j)) {
               count++;
           }               
       }
       difference_array[i] = count;
   }
   return difference_array;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Initialize count above inner loop and put `difference_array[i] = count;` out of inner loop.

Comment: the place it currently is at is not optimal but is not a bug since it does not change the program behaviour.